# Synchronization with semaphores

Tags: c, pthreads

```
typedef struct 
  {
  int count;
  pthread_mutex_t mutex;
  } Counter;

typedef struct 
{
  int countA;
  int countB;
  pthread_mutex_t mutex;
} Counter2;

void* TFa();
void* TFb();

Counter *cA;
Counter *cB;
Counter2 *c;

sem_t *S1, *S2;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    S1 = (sem_t *) malloc(sizeof(sem_t));
    S2 = (sem_t *) malloc(sizeof(sem_t));
    sem_init(S1,0,1);
    sem_init(S2,0,1);
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    pthread_t *t1;
    pthread_t *t2;
    cA= (Counter *) malloc (sizeof(Counter));
    cB= (Counter *) malloc (sizeof(Counter));
    c= (Counter2 *) malloc (sizeof(Counter2));
    cA->count =0;
    cB->count =0;
    c-> countA =0;
    c-> countB =0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&cA->mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&cB->mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&c->mutex, NULL);
    t1 = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*n);
    t2 = malloc((sizeof(pthread_t)*2*n));

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        pthread_create(&t1[i], NULL, TFa, NULL);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        pthread_create(&t2[i], NULL, TFb, NULL);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}

void* TFa()
{

    pthread_mutex_lock(&cA ->mutex);
    int num = cA->count;
    cA->count++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cA->mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock (&c->mutex);
    if(c->countA ==0 && c->countB ==2 )
    {
        printf("A%d 1n", num);
        c->countA =0;
        c->countB=0;
        sem_post(S1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&c->mutex);


    }
    else if(c->countA ==0 && c->countB <2)
    {   
        printf("A%d \n",num);
        c->countA ++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&c->mutex);
    }
    else
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&c->mutex);
        sem_wait(S1);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&c->mutex);
        printf("A%d \n", num);
        c->countA++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&c->mutex);

    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void* TFb()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cB->mutex);
    int num = cB->count;
    cB->count++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cB->mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&c->mutex);
    if(c->countA ==1 && c->countB ==1)
    {
        printf("B%d \n", num);
        c->countA =0;
        c->countB=0;
        sem_post(S2);
        sem_post(S2);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&c->mutex);
    }
    else if(c->countA <2 && c->countB ==0)
    {
        printf("B%d \n", num);
        c->countB++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&c->mutex);
    }
    else
    {
        phtread_mutex_unlock(&c->mutex);
        sem_wait(S2);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&c->mutex);
        printf("B%d \n", num);
        c->countB++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&c->mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I've got a problem with this little program:

> Implement a concurrent program in C language, using Pthreads, which generates n
>   threads th_A executing code A, and 2*n threads th_B executing code B.
>   The main thread takes argument n from the command line, and terminates without
>   waiting the termination of the threads it has created.
>   Both threads simply print their corresponding character, followed by their order of
>   creation number (from 0 to n-1 for th_A, from 0 to 2*n-1 for th_B).
>   After two Bs and an A characters have been printed, in whichever order, the last
>   printing thread must print the ’\n’ character.

But it does not compile and I'm not understanding way. Do you have some tips?

Comment: "Does not compile" isn't a clear problem statement. Please post the error messages you're getting.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: For code that does not compile, you should provide error messages.

Comment: If your code doesn't compile, you should be showing the compiler error messages.  What you see is not necessarily what we see.  But you should be asking yourself "why don't I understand the compiler's error messages".  Please make sure that you're proving an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: gcc -Wall -c "lab2_02.c" (nella cartella:/home/amidaraxar/Scaricati/Lab2.2)
lab2_02.c: In function ‘main’:
lab2_02.c:135:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
 }
 ^
lab2_02.c:135:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
At top level:
lab2_02.c:99:7: warning: ‘TFb’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 void* TFb()
       ^~~
lab2_02.c:60:7: warning: ‘TFa’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 void* TFa()
       ^~~
Compilazione fallita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        pthread_create(&t1[i], NULL, TFa, NULL);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        pthread_create(&t2[i], NULL, TFb, NULL);
```

These `{`'s don't have matching `}`s.

```
    phtread_mutex_unlock(&c->mutex);
```

You wrote p**ht**read instead of `pthread`.

With those two fixes and the missing `#include`'s, it compiles.